# How can I decrease logo size into 60px for tablet and 40 px for mobile in wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress, mobile

I'm using latest wordpress and builduppro themes.

Currently, I use logo size 90px for desktop, tablet and mobile.

I want logo size 90px for desktop only.

How can I decrease logo size into 60px(30%) for tablet and 40px(50%) for mobile?

website : http://logo.ayumall.com

I'm not a programmer and can't find any WP plugin to solve this problem.

Will appreciate any feedback.

I just edited on style.css but no luck.

```
@media screen and (max-width:768px) 
{
   .logo 
   {padding-top: 10px !important; text-align: left !important;}
}
```

Currently my Responsive.css :

```
/* Mobile Portrait View */
@media screen and (max-width:767px) {
.logo{ width:auto; float:none; text-align:center; padding:0;}}


/* Tablet View */
@media screen and (min-width:768px) and (max-width: 980px){
.logo{ float:none; text-align:left; width:auto;}}

@media screen and (max-width:1169px) and (min-width:981px) {
.logo{ float:left; width:auto}}

@media screen and (max-width: 980px){
.logo img{ height:auto;}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the opening bracket is missing in your code after ".logo"

```
    @media screen and (max-width:768px)    
{
```

.logo
    {

```
padding-top: 10px !important; text-align: left !important;}

}
```

Comment: Try to add @media css end of your css file

Comment: Add @media screen and (max-width: 980px)

.logo img {
    height: 60px !important;
} } to last of your css file

Comment: I just added code from yours but don't solve problem.

Comment: in which file you made changes? check the file is included when it is run. inspect the code in browser also

Comment: I made change in style.css. I just add responsive.css on question above please review.

Comment: change '@media screen and (max-width: 980px){
.logo img{ height:auto;}}' to '@media screen and (max-width: 980px){
.logo img{ height:60px !important;}}' in responsive.css file

Comment: Your codes solve my problem. Now it looks perfectly!!

Answer (score 0):

Checked your website.
You can achieve this by CSS. Put the following code in your stylesheet.

```
/* For Tablets */
@media screen and (max-width: 768px){
.logo img{height: 60px;}
}

/* For Mobile */
@media screen and (max-width: 480px){
.logo img{height: 40px;}
}
```

Make sure to remove your cache after making these changes to css.
Hope it helps.

Comment: I just added the codes above, save it and clear browser cache but still no luck!